# MS Access 2013 multiple iff conditions compare previous row

Tags: ms-access

I've done something similar to this(but not as complex) in ms excel before but I am not sure how to approach this in ms access 2013.

I have an ordered table by product number that may or may not have a duplicate number, but one or another field may be different. I would like to create an iff statement in which it compares the two fields (color and size) with the previous product number and if either color or size is different then a new column (Change) will state either color or size. And if the product number is new (previous row's product number is not the same) then the Change column will show "New".

For example

ProductNo............Color........Size............Change

12...................yellow..........3.............size

12...................yellow..........2............Size

43....................pink..........3..............New

32...................orange.........1............color

32....................blue..........1............color

if this is not possible on access, what's the best approach to achieve something similar to this? Would be great if there's examples. :)

Answer (score 0):

loop through your recordset.  on each pass save your variables (eg.  LastColor, LastSize) and compare to current records.

(pseudocode)

```
LastColor = "", LastSize = "", LastProduct = ""
do while not end of file
   if product <> LastProduct then 
      Change = "New"
   else
      compare color/size to last-color/size and assign value to Change
   endif
   LastColor = Color, LastSize = Size, LastProduct = Product
   move to next record
loop
```

Comment: sorry I'm really new on coding....should this be in a vba onload procedure? How can I look through the recorset?

Comment: You can trigger any way you wish. Most tend to use onclick attached to a button or you can trigger after an update.  Note that the above is  not actual code but the logic for what youre trying to do.  You would need to research recordsets to start.